# Is there a way to make member function NOT callable from constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I have member function (method) which uses

```cpp
std::enable_shared_from_this::weak_from_this()
```

In short: `weak_from_this` returns `weak_ptr` to **this**. One caveat is it can't be used from constructor.
If somebody would use my function from constructor of inherited class, `weak_from_this` inside it would return expired `weak_ptr`. I guard against that with assertion checking that it's not expired, but it's a run-time check.

Is there a way to check against it at compile time?

Comment: Note there is a difference in scope between a child class constructor body and the parent class constructor: the latter has been executed completely before you even start initializing the child class's members (if any), let alone enter the child class constructor body.

Comment: Nice question. One way would be to make a dummy class with pure virtual function `weak_from_this` and inherit yours from it. This will make it a hard compile error.

Comment: @SergeyA Why didn't you post that as an answer? All other people here seem to conclude that it's not possible so either your comment is wrong and misleading or they are wrong and you should show how it can be achieved.

Comment: @Bakuriu well, I did not have the energy to polish it to the full blown answer. It is possible that it is not a workable solution.

Comment: Simply based on the fact the static type of an object doesn't (and cannot) depend on the fact its construction is completed. Note that if that were the case, you wouldn't be able in a ctor of `T` to store `this` in a global obj register, and use the obj later, w/o a cast, as the ptr stored would have "(in construction)T*" not plain `T*`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am afraid the answer is "no, it's not possible to protect against this at compile-time." It's always difficult to prove a negative, but consider this: if it was possible to protect a function this way, it would probably have been done for `weak_from_this` and `shared_from_this` in the standard library itself.

Answer (score 5):

No there is no way. Consider:

```
void call_me(struct widget*);

struct widget : std::enable_shared_from_this<widget> {
    widget() {
        call_me(this);
    }

    void display() {
        shared_from_this();
    }
};

// later:

void call_me(widget* w) {
    w->display(); // crash
}
```

The thing is there is a reason you want to check for not calling `shared_from_this` in the constructor. Think about that reason. It's not that `shared_from_this` cannot be called, it's because it's return value has no way of being assigned yet. It is also not because it will never be assigned. It's because it will be assigned *later* in the execution of the code. Order of operation is a runtime property of your program. You cannot assert at compile time for order of operation, which is done at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Not as such, but - if performance is not an issue, you could add a flag which indicates construction is complete, and use that to fail at run-time with such calls:

```
class A {

    // ... whatever ...
public:
    A() { 
        // do construction work
        constructed = true;
    }

    foo() {
        if (not constructed)  { 
            throw std::logic_error("Cannot call foo() during construction"); 
        }
        // the rest of foo
    }

protected:
    bool constructed { false };
}
```

You could also make these checks only apply when compiling in DEBUG mode (e.g. with conditional compilation using the preprocessor - `#ifndef NDEBUG`) so that at run time you won't get the performance penalty. Mind the `noexcept`s though.

An alternative to throwing could be `assert()`'ing.

Comment: Since apparently there isn't compile-time solution which doesn't make code less readable, I decided to go with `assert(!wptr.expired())`. I think it's a little bit more fitting than exception, because there is no way to recover from this situation.

Comment: @Korri remember that `assert`s are usually compiled out in release builds, so nothing will happen. An exception however is not, so it would still terminate the program (if not caught and swallowed) in a release build. You *could* do both; first `assert` then `throw`, or just `throw`.